# Can I check at compile time if a member function is an operator?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, type-traits

I am passing both the signature and the actual pointer of members function of a class as template parameters of a template class. Is there a way to have different specialization of such class for operator overloads? I tried to look in the `type_traits` and have an hint from `std::is_copy_assignable`, but it seems that g++ uses built-ins (`__has_trivial_copy` for example).

Comment: Do you want to know (a) that a certain pointer-to-member-function is an overloaded operator or (b) that eg. a template argument A actually implements A*A?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/category/value_traits/operators.html

Comment: (a). I guess though that the implementation would have to check that the type to which the pointer-to-member-function belongs implements the operator being checked.

Comment: Can you provide some code example ?

Comment: So you need to check the existence of `A::operator*`. That's harder, I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: @Anonymous, the problem is that with boost you have to specify what argument types the operator takes. I would like to check the mere existence of an operator. iammilind, I have no code yet as 'm still in the planning phase. Basically, it's for extending this framework to support operators: https://github.com/pisto/SpaghettiMod/tree/master/src/hopmod/lua/luaproxy See luaproxy.hpp and especially member_helper

Comment: If you have a pmf, you have the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I worked on this question.

I think that it's possible to get the result, but it's rather complicate because the class A that wants to know if one of its own template arguments is an operator of class B, it must first check that B::operator exists, then check if it equals the template argument. This quickly increase the difficulty of the task.

Moreover, I found while testing, that g++ has still very poor support for advance template usage. For example, this code does step 2, that is assumed that a certain member function exists, check if the template argument is equal to the same member function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Hello{
    int helloworld(){
        return 0;
    }
    int goodbyeworld(){
        return 0;
    }
};

template<typename T1, T1, typename T2, T2> struct is_same_method{
    static constexpr bool value=false;
};

template<typename Return, typename Class, typename... Args, Return(Class::*member)(Args...)>
struct is_same_method<Return(Class::*)(Args...), member, Return(Class::*)(Args...), member>{
    static constexpr bool value=true;
};

#define method_test(a, b) is_same_method<decltype(a), a, decltype(b), b>::value


template<typename T, T> struct what_am_I_passed;

template<typename Return, typename Class, typename... Args, Return(Class::*member)(Args...)>
struct what_am_I_passed<Return(Class::*)(Args...), member>{
    static void so_what(){
        /*
         * error: ‘decltype (& Class:: helloworld)’ is not a valid type for a template constant parameter.
        */
        cout<<"you passed me "<<(method_test(member, &Class::helloworld)?"helloworld":"something else")<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    what_am_I_passed<decltype(&Hello::helloworld), &Hello::helloworld>::so_what();
}
```

Now, this code fails with g++ 4.4, 4.5, crashes 4.6.1, and works from 4.6.2 on.

After all these troubles I decided to port some of the logic at runtime. This is what I ended up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template<typename mem_type, mem_type mem> struct operator_type{
    enum types{
        //complete me...
        NONE=0, ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, MOD, POW, UNM, EQ, NEQ, LT, LE, GT, GE, SUBSCRIPT, CALL
    };
    static types what(){ return NONE; }
};

typedef operator_type<int, 0>::types op_types;

template<typename Return, typename Class, typename... Args, Return(Class::*mem)(Args...)>
class operator_type<Return(Class::*)(Args...), mem>{

#define isOp(name, symbol, args)\
        template<typename Class_,int=0> static bool is##name(float&&){ return false; }\
        template<typename Class_, Return(Class_::*innermem)(Args...)=&Class_::operator symbol>\
        static bool is##name(int&&){ return innermem==mem  && (args<0 || sizeof...(Args)==args); }
#define testOp(name)    if(is##name<Class>(0)) return op_types::name

    //complete me...
    isOp(ADD, +, 1)
    isOp(SUB, -, 1)
    isOp(MUL, *, 1)
    isOp(DIV, /, 1)
    isOp(MOD, %, 1)
    isOp(POW, ^, 1)
    isOp(UNM, -, 0)
    isOp(EQ, ==, 1)
    isOp(NEQ, !=, 1)
    isOp(LT, <, 1)
    isOp(LE, <=, 1)
    isOp(GT, >, 1)
    isOp(GE, >=, 1)
    isOp(SUBSCRIPT, [], 1)
    isOp(CALL, (), -1)

public:

    static op_types what(){
        //complete me...
        testOp(ADD);
        testOp(SUB);
        testOp(MUL);
        testOp(DIV);
        testOp(MOD);
        testOp(POW);
        testOp(UNM);
        testOp(EQ);
        testOp(NEQ);
        testOp(LT);
        testOp(LE);
        testOp(GT);
        testOp(GE);
        testOp(SUBSCRIPT);
        testOp(CALL);
        return op_types::NONE;
    }
};




template<typename T, T> struct wants_to_know_operators;

template<typename Return, typename Class, typename... Args, Return(Class::*mem)(Args...)>
struct wants_to_know_operators<Return(Class::*)(Args...), mem>{
    typedef operator_type<decltype(mem), mem> my_operator_type;
    static void stuff(){
        switch(my_operator_type::what()){
        case op_types::NONE:        cout<<"this is not an operator"<<endl; break;
        case op_types::CALL:        cout<<"this is operator()"<<endl; break;
        case op_types::SUBSCRIPT:   cout<<"this is operator[]"<<endl; break;
        case op_types::SUB:         cout<<"this is operator-"<<endl; break;
        case op_types::UNM:         cout<<"this is operator- (unary)"<<endl; break;
        //complete me...
        default: cout<<"something else..."<<endl; break;
        }
    }
};

struct Test{
    void operator()(){

    }
    Test& operator-(){
        return *this;
    }
    Test& operator-(int){
        return *this;
    }
    int operator[](int){
        return 0;
    }
    int operator[](iostream){
        return 0;
    }
    int operator==(int){
        return 0;
    }
    void f(){}
};


int main(){
    wants_to_know_operators<decltype(&Test::f), &Test::f>::stuff();
    wants_to_know_operators<int(Test::*)(int), &Test::operator[]>::stuff();
    wants_to_know_operators<int(Test::*)(iostream), &Test::operator[]>::stuff();
    wants_to_know_operators<decltype(&Test::operator()), &Test::operator()>::stuff();
    wants_to_know_operators<decltype(&Test::operator==), &Test::operator==>::stuff();
    wants_to_know_operators<Test&(Test::*)(), &Test::operator- >::stuff();
    wants_to_know_operators<Test&(Test::*)(int), &Test::operator- >::stuff();
}
```

The syntax is somewhat cumbersome but it's the best I could work out with templates. Notice that it can distinguish between different overloads for the same operator. For my goal, this is sufficient and maybe even preferable, because the whole thing is about exporting C++ function to Lua, and of course you cannot push stuff on the Lua stack at compile time.

Comment: So your code worked in the current release of the compiler but you say it "still has very poor support" ... hmm, interesting criteria you have there. Maybe you mean old versions of gcc that predate C++11 _had_ poor support for that unfinished standard? :)  P.S. if you found bugs still present in the current releases I hope you reported them, they won't get fixed if noone reports them.

Comment: @JonathanWakely maybe I sounded too drastic. I meant that even with a little hobbyistic project as mine, I faced bugs (not missing implementations, bugs) in recent versions of g++. Also, the support seems somewhat "volatile", because I encountered also some regressions in g++ 4.6 or 4.7. This is totally understandable, being C++11 very new and the feature set pretty much advanced. Of course, I report most of the stuff I find. See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52744 http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53009 http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53181